# Kotlin recyclerView nextFocusDown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to make nextFocusDown on items in recyclerView. Every item has the same id, but to make nextFocusDown I need to have specific id. How shoudl I do this in recycerView to make focus on next edittext in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put focus on your edit text programmatically. Get the event when the user presses enter button or some button that tells you the user is done editing the first edit text. Then you can programmatically put focus on next item in recyclerview using following code:

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```